# How to change the content of ViewResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewresult

```
bool isChecked = false;
<input type="checkbox" name="x" checked="@isChecked" />
```

In MVC 4, The above code will be generate as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x" />
```

But in MVC 3,Need to write like this:

```
bool isChecked = false;
@if(isChecked)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="x" checked="checked" /> 
}
else
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="x" /> 
}
```

If we are Microsoft developers, Which assembly need to modify and how to modify it? 
How to customize the upgrade code?
Plase help me,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I don't really understand the question after those code blocks, but I can say that you can use inline condition in your views in ASP.NET MVC3. Something like that for example:

```
bool isChecked = false;
<input type="checkbox" name="x" @(isChecked ? "checked=checked" : "") />
```

It's shorter and it will produce code like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x">
```

And BTW, there is a helper method `Html.CheckBox` to create checkbox in your view and in second parameter you can indicate if you want it to be checked:

```
@{bool isChecked = false;}    
@Html.CheckBox("x", isChecked)
```

And that will rendrer this:

```
<input id="x" type="checkbox" value="true" name="x">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="x">
```

Try it on your own.

Comment: Thanks, But I want a solution similar to the official.

Comment: What do you mean by the official solution? What's "not official" in using `Html.CheckBox` helper method or inline condition? Using helper method is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Because I want to read the contents of a cshtml to match some things.For example, for each input box to add a "class" attribute.

Comment: @LooseLive Please  update yout question with info about everything you want to do exactly.

Comment: @LooseLive, if you want help, you have to meet ppl at least half way. In this case you're asking Konrad to read your mind. When I get help, even if the person misses my intent, I am appreciative that someone is trying to help me.